# Django MPTT fail with auth.view.login View

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm having problem with Django MPTT using django.contrib.auth.view.login View,

In urls.py there is

```
  (r'^accounts/login/$', django.contrib.auth.view.login),
```

and my template registration/login.html extends base template-login.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Now, I use MPTT in base.html, like this:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}    
            <ul>
           {% recursetree nodes %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url someview node.id %}">{{ node.name }}</a>
                {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                    <ul>
                        {{ children }}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endrecursetree %}
```

However when I access accounts/login django complains:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/

Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [nodes] in u"[{}

Template error

In template /home/user/djcode/project/templates/base.html, error at line 58
```

And on line 58 is actually this code        `{% recursetree nodes %}`

I'm not sure how I can fix this.I don't have problem with my other views, only this generic.However in  other views I also send data for navigation in dictionary, to template, but don't know how to do that with generic views.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to send your navigation tree to all views, including the generic ones, rather than passing it manually from each view.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the tip, just wrote my first context processor and it works great.Once again thanks.

Comment: I just have one more question about this context processor stuff.After writing this processor things started getting better, however, why in my view I am required to write as a 3rd argument context_instance=RequestContext(request) to render_to_response(), if I already added django.core.context_processors.request to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple?

Comment: `RequestContext` is what triggers the context processors to be run in the first place - the standard `render_to_response` doesn't do it. However you can use the newish [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead - that uses RequestContext internally.

Comment: I see, it doesn't matter what is in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS if  I don't actually call RequestContext...thanks!